# Programmatically change combobox

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, combobox, postmessage

I need to update a `combobox` with a new value so it changes the reflected text in it. The cleanest way to do this is after the `combobox`has been initialised and with a message.

So I am trying to craft a `postmessage` to the hwnd that contains the `combobox`.

So if I want to send a message to it, changing the currently selected item to the nth item, what would the `postmessage` look like?

I am guessing that it would involve `ON_CBN_SELCHANGE`, but I can't get it to work right.

Comment: Is there a language in particular you are looking for an example in? C++?

Comment: The clue is in the MFC tag :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [ComboBox_SetCurSel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb856484(VS.85).aspx):

```
ComboBox_SetCurSel(hWndCombo, n);
```

or if it's an MFC CComboBox control you can probably do:

```
m_combo.SetCurSel(2);
```

I would imagine if you're doing it manually you would also want SendMessage rather than PostMessage. CBN_SELCHANGE is the notification that the control sends *back to you* when the selection is changed.

Finally, you might want to add the c++ tag to this question.

Answer (score 1):

A concise version:

```
const int index = 0;
m_comboBox.PostMessage(CBN_SELCHANGE, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

What might be going wrong is the selection is being changed inside the selection change message handler, which result in another selection change message.

One way to get around this *unwanted feedback loop* is to add a sentinel to the select change message handler as shown below:

```
void onSelectChangeHandler(HWND hwnd)
{
  static bool fInsideSelectChange = 0;

  //-- ignore the change message if this function generated it
  if (fInsideSelectChange == 0)
  {
    //-- turn on the sentinel
    fInsideSelectChange = 1;

    //-- make the selection changes as required
    .....

    //-- we are done so turn off the sentinel
    fInsideSelectChange = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you fx want to change the title - which is the line shown when combobox is closed, then you can do following:

m_ComboBox.DeleteString(0); // first delete previous if any, 0 = visual string
m_ComboBox.AddString(_T("Hello there"));

put this in fx. in OnCloseupCombo - when event close a dropdownbox fires

```
ON_CBN_CLOSEUP(IDC_COMBO1, OnCloseupCombo)
```

This change is a new string not a selection of already assigned combobox elements

Comment: I would appreciate a comment when I am voted down, otherwise I can not take it serious