# What windows messages are used by Delphi to notice changes in a combo box?

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-2009

I have a Delphi application A, which I need to control from a .NET application B.

Among other things, I need to automate this process:

1. User selects item X from a combo box.
2. Application A notices the change and reacts by displaying a certain panel.

This works fine, if I do it manually.

But when the application B selects a combo box value, no panel is displayed.

This is the problem.

Potential cause of it:

1. When I select a combo box item, a certain windows message is fired. Some Delphi routine reacts to this message.
2. When I select a combo box item programmatically, the only message I send is `CB_SETCURSEL` and the Delphi app seems to ignore it.

Hence I assume that I can fix the problem, if I

1. get to know what windows messages are used as a basis for notification about combo box value changes (e. g. `OnChange`) and
2. send that windows message from C# application.

Therefore my question: What are the windows messages, on whose occurrence `OnChange` (and other events that notify the Delphi application on changed combo box selection) are fired?

**Update 1:** Started to implement the solution proposed by David Heffernan

```
private const int CB_SETCURSEL = 0x14E;
private const int WM_COMMAND = 0x0111;
private const int CBN_SELCHANGE = 0x001;
private const int CN_COMMAND = 0xBD11;

private int MakeWParam(int l, int h)
{
    return (l & 0xFFFF) | (h << 16);
}

...
IntPtr comboBoxHandle = new IntPtr(comboBox.Current.NativeWindowHandle);
SendMessage(comboBoxHandle, CB_SETCURSEL, (Int32)myIndexInComboBox, 0);
SendMessage(comboBoxHandle, CN_COMMAND, MakeWParam(0, CBN_SELCHANGE), 0);
```

At the moment, it doesn't work.

**Update 2:**

I noticed a very strange thing.

1. If I invoke `CB_SETCURSEL` only, the desired item is selected in the combo box.
2. If I invoke `CB_SETCURSEL` and then (after 5 seconds) `CN_COMMAND`, then nothing is selected in the combo box.

This means - `CB_SECURSEL` selects the item and `CN_COMMAND` undoes it.

**Update 3**: Styles of the combo box according to Spy++:

1. WS_CHILDWINDOW
2. WS_VISIBLE
3. WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
4. 00000243

Extended styles:

1. WS_EX_LEFT
2. WS_EX_LTRREADING
3. WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR

Class styles:

1. CS_VREDRAW
2. CS_HREDRAW
3. CS_DBLCLKS

**Update 4**: When I select the combo box item manually, I see following messages in the Spy++ output:

```
<00177> 0195085E S message:0xBD33 [Custom:WM_APP+15667] wParam:6801164A lParam:0195085E
<00178> 0195085E R message:0xBD33 [Custom:WM_APP+15667] lResult:4610165A
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find documentation for this message.

**Update 5**: I noticed that the reaction to combo box selection change does occur, but only after a relatively long time (30 seconds to 1 minute). When I do the same thing manually, the reaction occurs instantaneously.

Potential cause of this behaviour: The thread of the .NET application makes the thread of the Delphi application wait for it. Note that the UI interaction code in the .NET app is executed in a separate thread (not the UI thread).

Comment: The code in your update works in my test environment. The call to CN_COMMAND does indeed result in the `OnChange` event firing.

Comment: 0xBD33 is `CN_CTLCOLOREDIT`. A parent control in the VCL routes WM_CTLCOLORMSGBOX .. WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC messages to the notifying control itself offsetting the message with 0xBC00.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should follow the `CB_SETCURSEL` message by sending the combo box a `WM_COMMAND` message with `NotifyCode` equal to `CBN_SELCHANGE`. It's the `CBN_SELCHANGE` that triggers the `OnChange` event.

In Delphi the code would look like this:

```
SendMessage(ComboHandle, CB_SETCURSEL, NewSelectionIndex, 0);
SendMessage(ComboHandle, WM_COMMAND, MakeWParam(0, CBN_SELCHANGE), ComboHandle);
```

Or you could use the `CN_COMMAND` message instead which would perhaps be a little more direct:

```
SendMessage(ComboHandle, CB_SETCURSEL, NewSelectionIndex, 0);
SendMessage(ComboHandle, CN_COMMAND, MakeWParam(0, CBN_SELCHANGE), 0);
```

You'll want to translate that into whichever .net language you are using, but I'm sure that's easy for you.

Comment: Isn't this question about how to get notified in Delphi application about `CB_SETCURSEL` sent from C# application ?

Comment: I would check the result of sending `CB_SETCURSEL`: `if SendMessage(ComboHandle, CB_SETCURSEL, NewSelectionIndex, 0) = NewSelectionIndex then
    SendMessage(ComboHandle, WM_COMMAND, MakeWParam(0, CBN_SELCHANGE), ComboHandle);`

Comment: @TLama Yes it is. OP is sending `CB_SETCURSEL` but no sending `CBN_SELCHANGE`. And it's the latter that is translated into the `OnChange`. Without it the target Delphi app is not updating its UI which OP presumes is because `OnChange` is not firing. This answer shows how to provoke `OnChange`.

Comment: @TOndrej You could do that, but it doesn't hurt to send `CBN_SELCHANGE` in all cases.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Do you know the value of the `CN_COMMAND` constant? Is it equal to (0xBC00 + 0x0111) ?

Comment: Yes, it is `0xBD11`. It is defined as `CN_BASE + WM_COMMAND` and `CN_BASE` is `0xBC00`.

Comment: @David, about TOndrej's comment, in this case might *hurt*. If OP displays some panel when the `OnChange` is fired, sending `CB_SETCURSEL` with index out of bounds for instance may result to no visible change, but displayed panel.

Comment: @TOndrej First SendMessage call returns `NewSelectionIndex`.

Comment: I've tried both solutions (see update 1) and neither seems to work. At http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1468165/how-to-send-a-cbn-selchange-message-when-using-cb-setcursel a similar situation is discussed (see answer by Keith McCall), but `WM_COMMAND` is sent to the parent of the combo box, not to the combo box itself. I'll try it now.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko That won't help. Delphi reflects it back to the control as a `CN_COMMAND`. I tested this code. It works. The `OnChange` is fired.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If it works in your test environment, then following issue may interefere with my code: The .NET application B, which sends these commands to the Delphi application A, activates its main window every 200 milliseconds (it's a requirement that application B is always focused and its main window is always the top-most window). Can this (app B regaining the focus every 200 milliseconds) be the cause for `OnChange` not fired?

Comment: No, that should not influence this message which is delivered synchronously. I'd look at it under Spy++ and see that the message is delivered.

Comment: I noticed that `CN_COMMAND` seems to undo the selection done by the first call (see my update 2). Any ideas what may be wrong?

Comment: No idea. My test environment behaves fine. Do you have Delphi source for the target app?

Comment: No, I don't have the sources.

Comment: Difficult to know what to suggest. We obviously have different environments. I've just got a Delphi `TComboBox` on a form and am sending it these messages. Everything of mine is default.

Comment: See my update 4. Is there any documentation for windows message `0xBD33`?

Comment: Yes, it is CN_CTLCOLOREDIT which is a Delphi variant of WM_CTLCOLOREDIT used to reflect back from parent to child. It's no use to you. Is there really no `CBN_SELCHANGE` for your control? Is it really a combo?

Comment: One interesting point. If I send the WM_COMMAND not to the combo box, but to its list (these are two separate elements, and the list ist a child of the combo box), then the selection is not cleared.

Answer (score 4):

When the user selects a ComboBox item by hand, the control receives a `CBN_SELCHANGE` notification, which then triggers the `TComboBox.OnChange` event.  When you select a ComboBox item programmably, no `CBN_SELCHANGE` notification is sent.  This is documented behavior:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775821.aspx

> The CBN_SELCHANGE notification code is not sent when the current selection is set using the CB_SETCURSEL message.

Comment: Yep, that's the crux of my answer isn't it

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: You explained **how** to send a `CBN_SELCHANGE` notification manually (yes, you do need to use `CN_COMMAND` instead of `WM_COMMAND` when sending to the `TComboBox` window directly), but you did not explain **why** it is needed.  My answer explains the **why**.

Comment: Yeah. Actually you can send WM_COMMAND. Put the combo box handle in the LPARAM. Anyway, CN_COMMAND is cleaner.

Comment: `CN_COMMAND` is what `TComboBox` officially responds to. If you send `WM_COMMAND` directly to `CN_COMMAND`, it will get translated by `TWinControl` into `CN_COMMAND` and sent to whichever `HWND` is in the message's `lParam`. Either way, `TComboBox` will only trigger its `OnChange` event if the `ItemIndex` propety is not `-1`.