# Select an item in combobox of another application

Tags: delphi-xe2

I am making Delphi application to control other application. I need to select item in ComboBox of other application one by one and get its text. I have used FindWindowEx to find that ComboBox. Now I can find ComboBox but I don’t know how to select item in ComboBox.

```
var
  ParentWindow: HWND;
  ChildWindow: HWND;
begin
  ParentWindow := FindWindow('TfrmMain', nil);
  if ParentWindow <> 0 then
  begin
    ChildWindow := FindWindowEx(ParentWindow, 0, 'TPageControl', nil);
    ChildWindow := FindWindowEx(ChildWindow, 0, 'TTabSheet', nil);
    ChildWindow := FindWindowEx(ChildWindow, 0, 'TfrmInnerView', nil);
    ChildWindow := FindWindowEx(ChildWindow, 0, 'TPanel', nil);
    ChildWindow := FindWindowEx(ChildWindow, 0, 'TComboBox', nil);
  end;
end;
```

I wish someone tell me how to do it.

Comment: Use UIAutomation

Comment: @David Heffeman, Because I am beginner of Delphi; may you give me some clue which is easy to understand?

Comment: Start by doing some research using websearch and the keyword that I gave you. Don't expect to solve this in 10 minutes. And if you are a total beginner, then, with respect, this may be too big a challenge at the moment.

Comment: You can either [send window messages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bumper-combobox-control-reference-messages) like [CB_GETCOUNT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-getcount) and [CB_GETLBTEXT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-getlbtext), or use [UI Automation interfaces](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). Messages are easier to work with, but require manual marshaling of memory buffers across process boundaries. UI Automation is more complex, but handles marshaling for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case child window of **TfrmInnerView** have only one class named **TPanel**, the code below is working properly. But if your child window of **TfrmInnerView** has more than one class which has same name **TPanel**, code below can find only the 1st class **TPanel**. I am now looking for the ways to find 2nd class. I would appreciate for any idea to do it.

```
SendMessage(ComboHandle, CB_SETCURSEL, NewSelectionIndex, 0);
```

Use:  SendMessage(ChildWindow, CB_SETCURSEL, 1, 0);
I got this code from [[What windows messages are used by Delphi to notice changes in a combo box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782567/what-windows-messages-are-used-by-delphi-to-notice-changes-in-a-combo-box?rq=1])