# select a combobox via winapi in python

Tags: python, winapi

how do i select a comobobox with the winapi in python ?
my current code is the following.
It selects the the combobox item, but has no effect on the program.
It seems like no event is triggered.

```
import win32gui
import win32api
import win32con

class CBoxChanger:

    def run():
        #init vars
        self.count=0

        #get the desktop window
        lhWnd = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()

        #get the window window
        win32gui.EnumChildWindows(lhWnd, self.appHandler, l)

        #select toolbar
        win32gui.EnumChildWindows(self.window_hwnd, self.toolBarHandler, l)

        #select dialogbox
        GW_CHILD=5
        self.dialogbox_hwnd=win32gui.GetWindow(self.toolbar_hwnd,GW_CHILD)

        #select item nr 3
        index=2
        win32gui.SendMessage(self.dialogbox_hwnd,win32con.CB_SETCURSEL,index,0)



    def appHandler(self,lhWnd,lParam):
        text = win32gui.GetWindowText(lhWnd)
        if text=="WINDOWTITLE":
        self.window_hwnd=lhWnd

    def toolBarHandler(self,lhWnd,lParam):
        self.count+=1 
        if self.count==5:
            self.toolbar_hwnd=lhWnd
```

so how do i trigger the event needed for the program to process an reaktion on the selected combobox (like onclick, or onselect event)?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19290914/cb-selectstring-ignored-on-some-machines You may have to notify the Parent after a selection change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution: extend this

```
        #select item nr 3
        index=2
        win32gui.SendMessage(self.dialogbox_hwnd,win32con.CB_SETCURSEL,index,0)
```

with:

```
        #select item nr 3
        index=2
        win32gui.SendMessage(self.dialogbox_hwnd,win32con.CB_SETCURSEL,index,0)

        #trigger event
        win32gui.SendMessage(self.dialogbox_hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, 0)
        win32gui.SendMessage(self.dialogbox_hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, 0)
        win32gui.SendMessage(self.dialogbox_hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, win32con.VK_RETURN, 0)
        win32gui.SendMessage(self.dialogbox_hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, win32con.VK_RETURN, 0)
        win32gui.SendMessage(self.dialogbox_hwnd, win32con.CBN_SELCHANGE)
        win32gui.SendMessage(self.dialogbox_hwnd, win32con.CBN_SELENDOK)
```

i am not sure, if it is the simplest possible solution, but it works